# NumLock disabled after login

Tags: numlock

NumLock key stops working after user login Ubuntu 22.04.3 since last security update

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do that in linux :) `sudo apt install numlockx` is easiest way.

- [how can I set num lock on as the boot default in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240734/how-can-i-set-num-lock-on-as-the-boot-default-in-ubuntu-20-04)

An old Ubuntu topic:

- [How to enable numlock at boot time for login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155679/how-to-enable-numlock-at-boot-time-for-login-screen)

Methods from Arch also could work for you:

- [Activating numlock on bootup](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Activating_numlock_on_bootup)

But please take a note that `mkinitcpio.conf` is initramfs config. And you're probably on Gnome desktop environment. So GNOME advices and `.xinitrc` advices are also could work for you.